# Scala Map, ambiguity between tuple and function argument list

Tags: function, scala, dictionary, tuples, infix-notation

```
val m = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Int]()
// this doesn't work
m += ("foo", 2)
// this does work
m += (("foo", 2))
// this works too
val barpair = ("bar", 3)
m += barpair
```

So what's the deal with `m += ("foo" , 2)` not working? Scala gives the type error:

```
 error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.lang.String("foo")
 required: (String, Int)
       m += ("foo", 2)
             ^
```

Apparently Scala thinks that I am trying to call `+=` with two arguments, instead of one tuple argument. Why? Isn't it unambiguous, since I am not using `m.+=` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately `a b (c, d, e, ..)` desugars to `a.b(c, d, e, ..)`. Hence the error.

Comment: In addition to that, here is a workaround `m += ("foo" -> 2)` or even `m += "foo" -> 2`.

Comment: @Tempus: It desugars the way it does, because that's how the language works. Apropos the rationale for this decision, I remember there was some thread on [scala-user] discussing this issue. I am unable to find it at the moment. I will post the link if I manage to dig up that thread.

Comment: Can you cite formal Scala doc to support this? (Is this by design or is it considered a bug?)

Comment: @DanBurton: See [Scala 2.9 language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), page 85, first paragraph after the bullets at top.

Comment: @DanBurton: And yes, that's by design.

Comment: The corresponding reference for Scala 2.13 is at [SLS 6.12.3 Infix Operators](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#infix-operations)

Answer (score 4):

> Isn't it unambiguous, since I am not using m.+= ?

No, it isn't, because parenthesis can always be used when there are multiple arguments. For example:

```
List(1, 2, 3) mkString ("<", ", ", ">")
```

So you might ask, *what multiple parameters*? Well, the Scala API doc is your friend (or mine, at least), so I present you with:

```
scala> val m = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Int]()
m: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Int] = Map()

scala> m += (("foo", 2), ("bar", 3))
res0: m.type = Map(bar -> 3, foo -> 2)
```

In other words, `+=` takes a vararg.

Comment: The freedom to add a space before the open paren of arguments irritates me >,<

Answer (score 3):

The preferred way to define map entries is to use the -> method.  Like

```
m += ("foo" -> 2)
```

Which constructs a tuple.  a -> b gets desugared to a.->(b).  Every object in scala has a -> method.