# Weird scala tuple behavior

Tags: scala

I've notice this behavior in Scala

```
val list = List[(Int, Int)]()
val set = HashSet[(Int, Int)]()

scala> list :+ (1, 2)
res30: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2))

scala> list :+ (1 -> 2)
res31: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2))

scala> list :+ 1 -> 2
res32: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2))

//Work
// But the same for set not work
set += (1, 2)
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(2)
 required: (Int, Int)
       set += (1, 2)

//Ok may be += in set mean add all that mean this should work
set += ((1, 2))
set += ((1, 2), (3,4))
// Worked

// But why this one work
set += 1 -> 2
set += (1 -> 2)
set += ((1 -> 2))
```

Now I'm confuse, could you explain why tuple is not tuple?

```
scala> (4->5).getClass
res28: Class[_ <: (Int, Int)] = class scala.Tuple2

scala> (4,7).getClass
res29: Class[_ <: (Int, Int)] = class scala.Tuple2$mcII$sp
```

Answer (score 5):

I think the difference is that `HashSet[T]` defines two overloads for `+=`, one of which takes a single `T`, and the other takes multiple (as a `T*` params list). This is inherited from `Growable[T]`, and shown [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/collection/generic/Growable.html).

[`List[T].:+`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) can only take one `T` on the right hand side, which is why the compiler works out that it's looking at a tuple, not something that should be turned into a params list.

If you do `set += ((1, 2))` then it compiles. Also, `val tuple = (1,2); set += x` works too.

See Mario Galic’s answer for why in the case of `HashSet[T].+=` the compiler chooses the overload that can't type over the one that can.

Answer (score 5):

The parser stage `-Xprint:parser` gives

```
set.$plus$eq(1, 2)
```

which seems to [resolve](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/bbff536a4ad69af1516d0926562f35d92280e3ba/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/Growable.scala#L52) to

```
def += (elem1: A, elem2: A, elems: A*)
```

that is a method that accepts multiple arguments so compiler probably thinks `elem1 = 1` or `elem2 = 2` instead of considering `(1,2)` as a tuple.

[missingfaktor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744259/scala-map-ambiguity-between-tuple-and-function-argument-list#comment9427522_7744348) points to [SLS 6.12.3 Infix Operations](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#infix-operations) as the explanation

> The right-hand operand of a left-associative operator may consist of
>   several arguments enclosed in parentheses, e.g. ;op;(1,…,).
>   This expression is then interpreted as .op(1,…,).

Now the operator `+=` is left-associative because it does not end in `:`, and the right-hand operand of `+=` consists of several arguments enclosed in parentheses `(1,2)`. Therefore, by design, the compiler does not treat `(1,2)` as `Tuple2`.